# Sluggish performance of Gallery Control with large amount of items

Tags: office-365, powerapp

We're using Gallery control to render items stored in a collection by adding labels as a grid. The collection is being populated via Flow and can have around 10,000 items.

When the gallery is rendered, the page hangs and is totally unusable. Is there a workaround for this?

Note: We've already optimized our response time by fetching all the data as JSON and saving it in a collection. We can't use DataTable as the columns being used are dynamic and data table requires us to set columns explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd redesign this. It's not likely that anyone is actually going to look at 10,000 records. Is there nothing you can use to filter the rows to limit the number of items in the collection? Also, OOB the data row limit is 2000, so any tricks you're using to try to get around that are ... not a best practice.